# generate QR code with PHP QR Code Library

Tags: php, qr-code

I want to generate QR code with PHP QR Code Library.

When I write code like:

```
<?php
include "phpqrcode/qrlib.php";

// create a QR Code with this text and display it
QRcode::png("My First QR Code");
?>
```

But it is creating with all browser. I need QR code in specific place.

Comment: sorry, not understanding the question

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. PHP QR Code Library used for generating QR code. But when this code runs, then QR code is generating. But it takes whole background of browser and give color black in background. I need customized this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you don't need to store the QR code image, you can call the script that outputs the image as if it was an image:

```
<img src="qr_out_file.php">
```

with `qr_out_file.php` being the code from the question

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation](http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/) your code:

```
QRcode::png("My First QR Code");
```

is creating a png image of a qr code for the text string `My First QR Code` and returning the generated .png as the response.

What you need to do is create the qr code as a file like such:

```
QRcode::png('code data text', 'filename.png'); // creates file
```

saving it into the appropriate directory on your server. Then on your webpage where you are wanting to display it, just use a simple `<img>` tag.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But its give nothing. Means blank.